# Surface Integrals History

Tags: calculus, mathematical-physics

Can't find any information about who and when first used surface/surface area integrals. What was the original motivation? In it's modern form it depends on some relatively modern notations like partial derivatives and cross product (both mid 1800's if I'm not mistaken), but I have a sense it predates these. Then how did it look originally? Are there any records at all?

Comment: Partial derivatives are older than you say: they were used from the beginning of Calculus. For example Laplace equation was introduced in 18th century, while the wave equation is even older.

Comment: An early example I was just looking at is in Gauss's *Theoria attractionis corporum sphaeroidicorum ellipticorum homogeneum* (1813) and this built on the work of Laplace and Legendre, among others, so they might have an earlier use.

Comment: Couple of references online cite Lagrange in 1760 as the introduction, and his 1811 edition of Mécanique Analytique as a more formal introduction. I browsed through his Oeuvres vol  1 (which covers the years around 1760) but nothing jumped out immediately. Also not clear to me yet what happened in the intervening 51 years, or whether gauss knew about the development in Mécanique Analytique

Comment: In Bk. I, Sect. XII of the *Principia*, Newton integrated the gravitational attraction of a spherical surface at a point inside the sphere (Thm. LXX, Prob. XXX) and at a point outside the sphere (Thm. LXXI, Prob. XXXI). It is done without calculus and without modern notions of functions or vector fields. But as to motivation, it is clearly a surface integral to be solved.